# How to include information about labels in a multilabel classification task

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, transformer, multilabel-classification, ai

Currently, I'm working on a multilabel classification problem for a shared task in NLP. I have quite a few labels, and with those labels, I have a little paragraph defining them. I was wondering if there is some way I can include that label information in a multilabel classification pipeline.

Up until now, I've tried prompt-learning, designing a prompt that includes that paragraph, but I haven't obtained good results. My best shot so far has been using a fine-tuned RoBERTa model, and I thought that if I could include that label definition somehow in the pipeline, I could obtain better results, as the LM beneath could extract more information about it.

Thanks in advance! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It seems more like a weighting issue because the labeled data would be more differentiated than the other ones.

To avoid this problem, a solution is to generate labels automatically using Bert or any other NLP classification algorithm.

It should be quite simple: you have to write some summaries that would be the objective of a summary model. The labels would be the input features.

https://towardsdatascience.com/extractive-summarization-using-bert-966e912f4142

The summary model would be able to generate the missing paragraphs.

Once you have even labels, the results with Roberta would be much better.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like a really neat idea, I will read about it and see what can I come up with :) However, I think I haven't grasped the concept quite clearly. Do I have to use a model in which I give all the information about my labels as input (it would be a summary) and I would receive labels as output? Are those labels words, or logits? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The aim is to first generate summaries. Therefore, you need to train a model based on existing labels and objectives (paragraph summaries) you define yourself or another NLP algorithm (ex: could be a summary based on a simple structure of labels to make realistic sentences). Then, you would be able to classify very well with your Roberta model.